# Why does the defendant area look so different in Fracture

Tags: plot-explanation, fracture

In [***Fracture***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0488120/), the defendant is standing in a cage-like thing in court.

[image]

Why does the defendant area look so different in Fracture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an arraignment hearing (not a trial) where the formal charges are read to the accused.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arraignment)

> Arraignment is a formal reading of a criminal charging document in the presence of the defendant to inform the defendant of the charges against him or her. In response to arraignment, the accused is expected to enter a plea.

Although they are legal requirement they are much less formal affairs than the full trial.

Judges will see many defendants during any particular session to hear the charges read and hear pleas. Consequently, the accused persons will be brought straight from jail in bulk and run through the process in quick succession and may just hear the charges read and enter a plea. The process for **each accused** may take less than 10 minutes.

Once the trial has been set, a more formal setting is seen..

[image]